# Css and Javascript problem with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, css, thymeleaf

I'm trying to import a stylesheet and a javascript file in my web app project (Tomcat Server).

When I run it I noticed this strange error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

It's also strange because I can see in source section (using Chrome developer tool) my js and css files but the content is the same of my html file and not the one of my css and js files.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Grafico Temperature</title>
    <link href="../css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="../js/dayChart.js" th:src="@{/js/dayChart.js}" defer></script>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 80%">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="width: 50%">
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data e ora</th>
            <th>Temperatura Superiore Bollitore</th>
            <th>Temperatura Inferiore Bollitore</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="measure : *{session.MeasurementList}">
            <td th:text="*{measure.getDate()}">GG/MM/AAAA</td>
            <td th:text="*{measure.getTemperatureList()[0].getTemperature()}">value</td>
            <td th:text="*{measure.getTemperatureList()[1].getTemperature()}">value</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Data e ora</th>
            <th>Temperatura Superiore Bollitore</th>
            <th>Temperatura Inferiore Bollitore</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps your mime types aren't serving the js files?

Comment: One of your links is broken and redirecting to a 404 error page (which starts with `<`)

Comment: I noticed that also visiting other pages the content of my css file (in Chrome Source panel) is the code of my html page. Why that? I think is that the problem because css and js file in this case will start with `<!DOCTYPE html> ` so with `<`

Comment: Like I said, the links to your css/js files are broken, and when the browser tries to request them, the server sends a 404 error page instead, which is an html document and starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>`